# Is Cypress-BrowserStack integrated test suite can also be integrated with Allure to generate reports?

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing, allure, browserstack

I have a test suite designed using Cypress. In recent times I have integrated it with BrowserStack Automate to overcome some proxy issues. However the test suite is executing well, I am not happy with the way BrowserStack reports look. So, I want to know whether it can be integrated with Allure to get a beautiful report?

I have code that works perfectly to generate allure reports with cypress alone command
`npx cypress run --env allure=true`
But when I try the same using BrowserStack integrated cypress command, allure-results folder isn't getting generated
`browserstack-cypress run --sync --env allure=true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try adding the following to your browserstack.json file:

```
{
...
"run_settings": {
  ...
  "downloads": ["./results", "./allure-results"],
  "package_config_options": {
      "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
        "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true
      }
  },
  ...
}
...
}
```

And make sure that the necessary packages too are included, and this should help you achieve generating the Allure reports.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried this way but it didn’t worked. Allure-results folder itself is not getting generated even allure=true is set.

Comment: Please create the folder manually and specify the following in your Browserstack.json under run settings:

{
        "allure": true,
        "allureResultsPath": "/Users/grand-el/Desktop/terminaltest/nodejs/cypress/reports"
    }

Comment: I created a folder and in run settings I added allure, allureResultsPath values. But it didn’t worked, still the same. Can you clearly elaborate step-by-step?

Comment: Please refer to this document: 
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/cypress/custom-reports-build-artifacts

make sure you have all the necessary packages installed. 

And run the following command. 
yarn browserstack-cypress run --sync --reporter mocha-allure-reporter

Comment: the results folder is getting created in a specific path under build_artifacts how to change it to custom folder?

Comment: I think that will get created in the root folder and we ideally cannot control that because the reporting is managed by the respective node module.